# nested array to matrix array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a nested array that I need to write into the Excel file, making it not nested.

I have array like this:

```
[
    'a' => [
        'q1' => [36],
        'q2' => [
            54 => [88]
        ]
    ],
    'c' => [
        'e1' => [10, 90, 23],
        'e2' => [
            'n1' => [12]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I need convert array to like this:

```
[
    ['a', 'q1', 36],
    ['a', 'q2', 54, 88],
    ['c', 'e1', 10],
    ['c', 'e1', 90],
    ['c', 'e1', 23],
    ['c', 'e2', 'n1', 12]
];
```

Comment: Did you at least try some code of your own?

Answer (score 0):

Given the rigid nature here, we can just use multiple loops and gather the keys/values wanted.  If your leaf node is an array - there we want the key and value for that single entry:

```
<?php 
$data =
[
    'a' => [
        'q1' => [
            36
        ],
        'q2' => [
            54 => [88]
        ]
    ],
    'c' => [
        'e1' => [
            10, 
            90, 
            23
        ],
        'e2' => [
            'n1' => [12]
        ]
    ]
];

$result = [];
foreach($data as $i => $j) {
    foreach($j as $p => $q) {
        foreach($q as $y => $z) {
            if(!is_array($z)) {
                $result[] = [$i, $p, $z];
            }
            else {
                $result[] = [$i, $p, $y, reset($z)];
            }
        }
    }
}
// Display the result for readability:
foreach($result as $line)
    echo implode(',', $line), "\n";
```

Output:

```
a,q1,36
a,q2,54,88
c,e1,10
c,e1,90
c,e1,23
c,e2,n1,12
```